# INSERT or REPLACE into FTS table

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search

Here is my database structure

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE Products_fts USING fts4(PrdID, ConcatSearchField)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CategoryProduct_MM_CatID_PrdID_idx ON CategoryProduct_MM(CategoryID,PrdID)
CREATE INDEX CategoryProduct_MM_CatID_idx ON CategoryProduct_MM(CategoryID)
CREATE INDEX CategoryProduct_MM_PrdID_idx ON CategoryProduct_MM(PrdID)
```

I need to update it from another table with the same structure.

```
Insert or Replace into Products_fts select * from mydb.Products_fts
```

Data is inserted, but it's duplicated. How to do INSERT OR REPLACE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FTS table contain hidden rowid field, that can be used to perform replace

```
INSERT OR REPLACE 
INTO Products_fts (rowid, PrdID, ConcatSearchField) 
SELECT PrdID AS rowid, PrdID, ConcatSearchField FROM mydb.Products_fts
```